# Django how to include auto of a post from admin

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django and do not want to create my own user profile as it seem a little advanced for me when this is my first django app.

Anyway, I want to create users from the localhost:8000/admin but when users say I the admin and my cousin want to post we can so people can know who posted. Here is my implementation but it fails.

```
class Post(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    body = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField('Created on', auto_now_add=False)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField( 'Updated on', auto_now=False)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    publish = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)


    def save(self, *args, **kargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)

        super(Post, self).save(*args, **kargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

The author field is the problem after import `from django.contrib.auth.models import User`
 I still don't know why am getting this error `(1054, "Unknown column 'posts_post.author_id' in 'field list'")` I hope this helps explain my problem.

Comment: It seems the *ForeignKey* to **author** doesn't exist in the database. Did you migrate the database after changing the model ? Which version of Django are you using ?

Comment: I did but have manipulated or deleted the table manually before

Comment: try deleting all the migration and \_\_cache\_\_ files in your app where the Post model resides, the makemigrations and migrate again and tell me what happens.

Comment: This is what i got `Synchronizing apps without migrations:` and in the end i got `Running migrations: No migrations to apply.`

Comment: Have you checked the database?  All the columns are there?

Comment: Can you post admin.py and the trace back or a bit more info about when the error happens. Is it in a view?